# How to implement Media player Listener In C# Xamarin Android?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, media-player, listener

I am developing one of my android app in xamarin platform in which i want to play audio using url and now i am able to play that file using url. So now i want perform following tasks where  got stuck.
1) play file with seek bar according to file buffer size .
2) Unable to implement media player listener like OnComplitionListener specially in Xamarin.

Here i want share code that only playing audio without seekbar and media player listeners.

```
public void OnlinePlayer(String filePath)
{    

    try {
        player.Reset ();    
        player.SetDataSource(filePath);
        player.SetAudioStreamType(Stream.Music);
    //  player.SetOnCompletionListener(this);
        player.Prepare();
        player.Start();
        player.PrepareAsync();

        player.Completion += delegate {
    };

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Console.WriteLine("OnlinePlayer()", "Exception in streaming mediaplayer e = " , e.Message.ToString());
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I resolve the 2nd part of your question in this way for the listener:

```
player.Completion += OnPlayer_Completion;
```

then

```
private void OnPlayer_Completion(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...your code...
}
```